# How to install Coq

Tags: coq, coqide

I have been installing Coq using the download links from the https://coq.inria.fr/ for both Windows and Mac. However, when I try `coqc` or `coqtop` on terminal or command prompt I get error messages saying that the command is not found. Although with that being said, I can still run Coq almost perfectly fine on the Coq IDE but when I compile buffer, in particularly the exercises from [Software Foundations](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis500/current/index.html), i get the following message.

```
Running: coqc -I '/Users/zhangsheng/Desktop/G/repos/Coqy/cis500' '/Users/zhangsheng/Desktop/G/repos/Coqy/cis500/Basics.v' 2>&1
```

From what I understand, `2>&1` seems to be some form of misdirection and I feel that is the reason why `coqc` and `coqtop` don't seem to work on my terminal/command prompt.

Could someone kindly suggest the 'best' way to install Coq on either Mac or Windows or both such that I don't get the problems I mentioned above?

Comment: For Mac you can use [opam](https://opam.ocaml.org) to install coq (opam is a source-based package manager for OCaml ecosystem). To install opam one can use [homebrew](http://brew.sh), which is a package manager for macOS (homebrew uses both binary and source-based packages).

Comment: @AntonTrunov: This recommendation seems to be a bit involved. Cannot Coq be installed directly from homebrew?

Comment: @Zimmi48 Oh, yes, you are right :) It's just when experimenting with Coq's versions and different packages, it's easier (for me) to use opam.

Comment: @AntonTrunov: Right, opam has some advantages, but for beginners I suppose it may result in unnecessary complications.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Thanks for your recommendation. Does using opam give me OCaml so that I can then do my installation by cloning the [Coq repo](https://github.com/coq/coq)? Would be good if I can get more explicit instructions on the installation process.

Comment: @Zimmi48 I don't mind it being involved as long as I can get a proper working version running.

Comment: You can get any OCaml version with opam. They have pretty good installation instruction on their site. You can also get a development version of Coq if you add this repo: `opam repo add coq-core-dev https://coq.inria.fr/opam/core-dev` (see [here](http://coq.io/opam/get_started.html))

Comment: @AntonTrunov I actually installed Coq using brew and the `coqtop` and `coqc` commands now work. But now I don't have the familiar CoqIDE and even if I tried using it, the `.vo` files don't work with it. Any recommendations for which editor to use for Coq that is similar to CoqIDE? What are the difference between opam installation compared to the `.dmg` file from the Coq website? Do I get a Coq with no packages for the opam installation? Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: (1) Sorry, I don't use CoqIDE and I haven't used the `.dmg` installer, I prefer package managers. (2) There is a tool that may be considered close to CoqIDE -- Visual Studio Code with the Coq extension for it. (3) All major Coq packages can be installed via opam (e.g. mathcomp). The packages have prefix `coq-` in their names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I am not a Windows or OSX user, I imagine that you're having this problem because the Coq installer does not update the system's `PATH` variable. This variable is a list of directories used by the terminal to look up the programs corresponding to commands you type. If you don't want to install Coq via a different method, you should probably find where the `coqc` and `coqtop` binaries are installed, and add these directories to your `PATH`. Here are a few references on how to do this: [OSX](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/), [Windows](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

Comment: I think the default install location (and the one to add to your path) is C:\Coq\bin.

Answer (score 0):

When using Mac, just run

```
brew install coq
```